# Possible wiring issue?

Tags: nissan, audio, wiring, pathfinder

The car in question is a 2012 Nissan Pathfinder. I’ve noticed that every time the car is turned off the stereo and the clock reset and I’m having to adjust it accordingly when I start it back up. While driving this morning I hit a bump in the road and it seemed like my battery cable disconnected but the car was still running, the dash lights and stereo went out and came back on when they came back on all the lights were lite up, the car DID NOT turn off (engine still running, still driving) the car drives fine but I think it may be a wiring issue. I’ve checked the battery cables they are secure and the battery is brand new

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this an aftermarket stereo?

Comment: No stereo is factory

Comment: I'm not sure about the power shutting off, but check your inside fuse box to see if there's a fuse gone out. This fuse would provide power to accessories while the vehicle is off. It's should be a rather low amperage fuse, like 5A or 10A. I'm not able to pull up a fuse box diagram for your Pathfinder at the minute. Hopefully there's a diagram at the fuse box itself (like on the back of the cover).

Comment: I checked the fuses all seem to be there, I’m going to check them now to see if any need to be replaced

Comment: Examine battery connections again, including ALL main grounds - chassis and engine block. Losing clock time can be as simple as loose radio connections and separate ground cable between radio and chassis to corroded battery terminals/chassis/engine block ground connection. Main power usually means one red cable feeding the main and secondary fuse panels and starter, two negative cables for chassis and engine block.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your symptoms happen to people who have a big, heavy key ring hanging from their ignition switch. The added weight wears out the ignition switch.

To check if your ignition switch is worn out, start your car normally. Then while idling in Park or Neutral and not while in motion, play with the key in the ignition switch. Force the key up, down, in, out, slightly clockwise and slightly counterclockwise, but not far enough to turn off the engine or to re-engage the starter.

Do the dash lights, clock or radio turn off or flash? Jiggle the key through all those motions several times to see if anything happens.

If you get any result other than everything staying on with no glitches, your ignition switch is worn out and should be replaced. And if you do have a heavy key ring, you might consider keeping your car keys detached from the heavy ring in the future.